# the extension of a quasi-nilpotent operator is also quasi-nilpotent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator  acting on a complex Banach space $X.$ Let $M$ be a subspace of $X$ invariant by $T$ such that the restriction of $T$ on $M;$ $T_{M}:M\longrightarrow M$ is quasi-nilpotent. What we can say about the operator $T_{\overline{M}}: \overline{M}\longrightarrow \overline{M};$ where $\overline{M}$ is  the closure of $M$)?  Under what conditions on $M,$ the extension $T_{\overline{M}}$ becomes quasi-nilpotent?

Comment: Is $T:X \to X$ continuous?

Comment: @Gerd yes is a bounded linear operator

Comment: In my answer I used the definition $\|A^n\|^{1/n}\to 0$  for $A$ being quasi-nilpotent. The answer may differ if you use the definition $\sigma(A) \subseteq \{0\}$ since $M$ can be incomplete.

Comment: @Gerd So if $M$ is incomplete and taking the definition of quasi-nilpotent defined by the spectrum, is there an example in which $T_{M}$ is quasi-nilpotent, but $T_{\overline{M}}$ is not ?

Comment: In fact, I don't know. In case I find an example, i will post ist.

Comment: @Gerd Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M$ is dense in $\overline{M}$ and $T$ is continuous we have $\|(T_M)^n\|=\|(T^n)_M\|=\|(T^n)_\overline{M}\|=\|(T_\overline{M})^n\|$ $(n \in \mathbb{N}).$ Thus
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\|(T_\overline{M})^n\|^{1/n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\|(T_M)^n\|^{1/n}=0
$$
which means that $T_\overline{M}$ is quasi-nilpotent.

Edit: The conclusion is also true under the spectral definition of "quasi-nilpotent" if the resolvent is defined as the set of complex numbers $\lambda$ such that $T_M-\lambda I_M:M \to M$ has a continuous inverse $(T_M-\lambda I_M)^{-1}:M \to M$. Again since $M$ is dense in $\overline{M}$ the inverse can be extended to an inverse of  $T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M}$. To see this note that $(T_M-\lambda I_M)^{-1}:M \to M$ can be extended to a continuous linear operator $B:\overline{M} \to \overline{M}$, say, without changing the norm, by the BLT-theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension, for example). Since $B(T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M})x=(T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M})Bx=x$ for all $x \in M$
we also have $B(T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M})x=(T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M})Bx=x$ for all $x \in \overline{M}$. Thus $B=(T_\overline{M}-\lambda I_\overline{M})^{-1}$.

Thus $\sigma(T_M) \subseteq \{0\}$ implies $\sigma(T_\overline{M}) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: the inverse of  $T_{M}-\lambda I_{M}$  can be extended to an inverse   of 
 $T_{\overline{M}}-\lambda I_{\overline{M}}$ ! Can you explain how ?

Comment: @Luffy I edited the answer.